# how to add custom ajax javascript to admin> product > add/edit >custom tabs like :price / general

Tags: product, admin

i want to add custom javascript to admin> product > add/edit >custom tabs like :price / general

what i want that there will be one drop down attribute on change of which i want to use ajax to autofill value in below textbox

for that i will be using ajax call on change of main dropdown

how can i do this.

i thought adding custom js code for that page only .

how can i do this i want magento like ajax loader when drop down change ?...

any help please could not find any proper guide or link for such case

Comment: Is the attribute already installed on the product, or do you need to create that attribute also?

Comment: i have created attribute . just need ajax calling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already created the attribute, you can add some layout XML to inject a helper script:

```
<adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs">
            <script>path/to/your/script.js</script>
        </action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
```

For the product edit area only. You can place this in your related module's layout XML or else in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/local.xml`. So in the JS, I presume you'll be observing the `change` event of the target `select` element. On trigger, you'll make an AJAX call to ... ? I don't know that either, but if it's going to route back through Magento to get that information, you will likely need to also setup a controller.

**Alternate Method**

Another way to get the JS in place is to specify an "input renderer" when installing your attribute. Here's an article on how to do that: http://inchoo.net/magento/adding-magento-attribute-with-custom-input-renderer/

To summarize the article, install your attribute like so:

```
..
$installer->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'example_field', array(
    'group'             => 'General',
    'type'              => 'text',
    'backend'           => '',
    'input_renderer'    => 'test/catalog_product_helper_form_example',
..
```

Notice the `input_renderer` field. This maps to a block which renders the form field for your attribute, like so:

```
class Namespace_Test_Block_Catalog_Product_Helper_Form_Example 
    extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Text
{
    public function getAfterElementHtml()
    {
        $html = parent::getAfterElementHtml();

        return $html . "<script>//your script here</script>";
    }
...
```

You might not want to do this because your attribute is already installed, but I tend to prefer this method because of how tightly it couples the JS with the attribute.

Comment: hi, yeah one qsn as your 2 ans seems good what to do to use if i have already created attribute via admin > manage attributes ??

Comment: ahh, ok. In that case, the first solution is the one you want. Add that layout XML to the `local.xml` file. The script must be a path relative to your store's root `/js` folder (in the example shown above). Then clear your cache, load up the page edit screen, and check your developer tools to verify that the JS source was loaded.

Comment: how can ajax in mageto style ??
in specific way of calling in that loader style.

Comment: Magento uses Prototype JS to bootstrap AJAX requests, see http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Responders/ -- this means that **any** time you call `new Ajax.Request()` the loader popup will appear automatically. Learn about AJAX in Prototype here: http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Request/